# Identifying chewed wires of my 2005 Ford Taurus

Tags: electrical, ford, wiring, part-identification, taurus

Some mice chewed up the wiring of my 2005 Ford Taurus. I have already replaced the spark plug wires, but I need help identifying the remaining wires and the parts to which they run.

Here's the first photo:

[image]

One of the wires runs to this, which has part number XLIF-18801-AB PBT-GF30. From the research I did, this seems to be a "radio interference capacitor". Can anyone confirm this? If it is, it seems inessential. Is there any danger in driving without fixing it?

Here's the second photo:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out what this part is. Does anybody have any idea?

Ideally, I'd like to try to splice in new wire, but I'd like to at least know what system I'm splicing into. Any help identifying these parts would be much appreciated.

Comment: you're correct on the first picture, second picture looks like a coolant temperature sensor. you could repin the second connector or replace it (most autoparts places will carry connectors). The radio capacitor would need to be replaced (probably from a dealer).

Comment: @Ben, thanks for the info! Am I right in thinking that the radio interference capacitor is relatively inessential (its only function is to limit radio interference)? If so, I can probably get away with not fixing it *right* away.

Comment: correct, but make sure that the wire/connector for the capacitor isn't exposed. I'm unsure of how it's wired in the 3.0 but I believe it's wired into the ignition system and if the wire shorted could cause no starts/stalling.

Comment: you may want to edit your question as well as shopping advice isn't allowed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct on the first picture, second picture looks like a coolant temperature sensor.

You could re-pin the connector in the second picture or replace it (most auto parts stores will carry connectors). If you're feeling adventurous unplug the connector and using a small screwdriver push out the pins. They'll have little locking tabs on them. Then you could solder the wires back together.

The radio capacitor would need to be replaced. You can leave out the PBT-GF30 part when looking for the part or trying to interchange with an aftermarket part. XLIF-18801-AB is all you need.

If the radio capacitor shorts to ground, it is wired into the power circuit for the ignition coils as well as most engine sensors and the engine computer. Either unplug the connector or cut and wrap any exposed wire in tape.